# Vuex and dynamic states. Is possible?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a store in Vuex with an empty state

```
const state = {
    data: {

    }
};
```

And a simple mutations for test to change value or add new data

```
const mutations = {
    changeOrAdd(state, {key,value}) {
        state.data[key] = value;
    }
};
```

If I do a commit to `changeOrAdd`, it is added to state BUT it doesn't have reactivity.

I did a simple trick to change a default value

```
const state = {
    data: {
        change: 0
    }
};
```

And in the mutation:

```
const mutations = {
    changeValueAttr(state, {
        key,
        value
    }) {
        state.data[key] = value;
        state.data.change++;
    }
};
```

And everytime I change or add a new value, it looks like a reactivity.

But, exists a way to do this without a "default" variable and without this stupid trick?

To add a new data in store vue and make it with reactivity?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Since your keys initially are not declared in data, `Vue` can't track the changes. You need to use `Vue.set` to reactively add properties, see [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const mutations = {
    changeOrAdd(state, {key, value}) {
        Vue.set(state.data, key, value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have to do something like: if key is undefined, Vue.set(), else state.data[key]=value. Or it just take one character because is called in @input... I don't if the best way, but works. Thanks again