# VueJS computed value undefined in component while Vuex store is correct

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using Vue/Vuex/Axios/Express, I am trying to disable a button whenever a user's lastAct is within the past day. I am able to retrieve the lastAct in the store, but my computed value is undefined.

Here is my express route:

```
// GET last act for current user
router.get('/last', auth.required, async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(' req is: ', req);
  const lastAct = await Act
    .query()
    .where('users_id', req.user.id)
    .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    .limit(1);
  res.json(lastAct);
})
```

my axios service:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
```

...

```
  fetchLastAct () {
    return Api().get('acts/last')
  },

  deleteAct (id) {
    return Api().delete('acts/' + id)
  }
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

...

import ActsService from './services/ActsService'

// import SubscriptionsService from './services/SubscriptionsService'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),

...

  },
  mutations: {

...

    setLastAct(state, lastAct) {
      state.lastAct = lastAct;
      console.log('store sets this last act: ', lastAct) // returns correct object
    }
  },
  actions: {

...

    async getLastAct({ commit }) {
      await ActsService.fetchLastAct()
        .then(resp => {
          console.log('this is the last act: ', resp); // returns correct object
          commit('setLastAct', resp.data[0]);
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {

    ...

    lastAct: state => {
      return state.lastAct;
    }
  }
})
```

and my component's computed value:

```
  computed: {
    ...,
    actedToday() {
      // const now = new Date();
      console.log('this is computed last act', this.$store.state.lastAct) //returns undefined
      return this.$store.state.lastAct
      // .created_at > now.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are missing `lastAct` in your `state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `lastAct` property into your initial state. Vue won track for dynamic property, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811786/vuex-and-dynamic-states-is-possible)

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's an [example](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/144/A-Vuex-Tutorial-by-Example---Learn-Vue-State-Management) that can help you understand how the store works.

Comment: this resource is very helpful. Thanks!